# Configuring JS frontend depending on how the app was deployed

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a Java+React web application. There are two options of how to deploy it:

1. You launch backend with Spring Boot and React with Node.js separately.
2. You build a .ear with bundle.js building with frontend-maven-plugin and then deploy it on an app server.

The thing is that in the first case Spring Boot launches, for example, on localhost:8080 and Node.js on localhost:8081, they need different ports. And in the second case everything is in the same place and with completely different address. For the second case, when I make requests from frontend to backend I can just skip domain name and write a path. But in the first case I have to specify domain name since backend has different domain name.

My question is how to solve this problem and make frontend understand how the app was deployed. I can think of something like passing an argument with node.js command or something, but not sure if that is a correct and neat way of doing that.

I can provide the code if needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can have the backend deployed in a subdomain

deploying in different place is the best solution

Since you are using react you can deploy it without the need for a node js server you can build and deploy it in a cdn and route all the request to the `index.html` unless you need SSR you dont need a Nodejs deployment you can deploy it in Firebase or netlify for instance as an SPA and have the java backend in a vps of your choice Suggestion:Heroku or digital ocean

**Suggestion**

api.example.com

Comment: while everything here sounds cool and all, you are suggesting to change the whole infrastructure which I can't afford to do. I need a more basic solution, without changing any tools I mentioned

Comment: please refer this [link](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) to deploy react within java

Comment: again, I have to use Node.js and launch frontend separately. This link is incorrect since it uses maven-frontend-plugin and keeps backend and frontend as one module.